# What is the maximum atmospheric pressure a human can tolerate?

Tags: life, humans

How much pressure can the human body tolerate before living is impossible (e.g. skin begins to rupture, etc.)?

Comment: If high pressure is equal within the human body and the atmosphere no skin will rupture.

Comment: Interesting question, but what are the implications for space exploration?

Answer (score 14):

The answers are found in the SCUBA diving world.  Diving is interesting in this sense in that 10m is roughly an increase in pressure of 1atm.

In general, you wont see humans doing well above 30atm.  300m is a "holy grail" of sorts for deep diving.  Only a [handful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_diving) of people have ever gone that far down.  And by a handful, I mean it's been done seven times, total.

NCBI provides a short paper with a [theoretical](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5110125/) limit of 1000m for humans, based on data we have collected from saturation divers to date.  That would be 100atm of pressure.

Somewhere in between is the claimed record for [deep diving](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/environment/a11136/how-deep-underwater-can-a-human-really-travel-17135739/) which is roughly 600m.

Slightly higher than that, we find synthetic testing of [Hydreliox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydreliox).  This was done in a chamber compressed to a simulated 700m (70atm).  It was found that there were issues with hydrogen narcosis at depths below 500m, no matter how they tweaked the mix.

I cannot find the link, but I came across a fascinating link months ago which described the different gases you can breathe and how deep you can go.  At somewhere in the 40m range, you start suffering from nitrogen narcosis, so its beneficial to use a mix without nitrogen to go lower, such as heliox.  However, at extreme depths, you start running into helium toxicity issues, and adding a little nitrogen in helps with that.  Yes, I said *helium* toxicity.  At high enough pressures, [the noble gasses start to kill us](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4337274/), and of the noble gasses, we use helium at those depths because it kills us the least!

Comment: +1 for a great answer, but it might be nice to point out why it's so surprising that Helium becomes toxic. Or at least add a link. Depressingly I can't actually even find anything about helium toxicity on the web.

Comment: @DRF It's really strange to hear that a noble gas has toxic effects.  It had *something* to do with the nervous system, but I forget what it was. And, like you, I can't find links.  It doesn't matter until something like 1000m, and there's not a whole lot of web-indexed content on what happens to the body at that point!

Comment: Right I assume the strangeness comes from the fact that noble gasses are inert and so you would not expect them to interact in any way other than possibly displacing stuff.

Comment: These only seven dives to more than 300 m do not include the dives of professional saturation divers using a divers bell at constant pressure for the transfer from surface to ground and back. These seven dives are done with decompression in the water not using a divers bell and saturation diving.

Comment: Maybe this: [Moving in extreme environments: inert gas narcosis and underwater activities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4337274/), DOI:10.1186/s13728-014-0020-7

Comment: @mathandy Thank you for that link!  That's an excellent citation that I was missing.  I have incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: Look for "High-pressure nervous syndrome" - that's what the helium toxicity is usually found under :)

Answer (score 6):

> How much pressure can the human body tolerate before living is
>   impossible

The maximum tolerated pressure by a diver. It can be over 65 atm or bars.
See: [Saturation_diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_diving)

Comment: 65 bar is possible using very special breathing gas mixtures only. Using compressed air is impossible at such a pressure.

Answer (score 4):

There does not appear to be a maximum pressure.  We hit a limit as Cort Ammon says but that is a matter of what we can breathe, not an actual pressure limit.  You get poisoned by going too deep, not crushed or torn apart.

Note that this does not preclude a hypothetical liquid breathing system.  While we do not know how to build something yet (there are liquids that can carry enough oxygen and are non-toxic.  The problem is it would take too much effort for our lungs to move it in and out) this is a technological limit, not a theoretical limit.

Comment: If the viscosity of the high pressure gas is to much for the chest muscles, the exchange of oxygen and carbon dioxide may be impaired.

Comment: @Uwe No--high pressure **liquid**.  The current human depth limit is due to toxicity of the breathing gases as pressure goes up, go deep enough and there's no gas that's safe to breathe.  However, there are liquids capable of dissolving enough gas--there have been demonstrations of small animals surviving them.  However, square-cube interferes, human lungs wouldn't be able to inhale/exhale it.  The problem is mass, not viscosity.

Comment: This is it. The question aims at mechanical effects of high pressure ("skin rupture etc.") which do not exist: The human body is very much like a water balloon with a few bones in it which is happy at any depth, even though it is mechanically very weak. The problem are the *chemical and biological effects* of gases at high partial pressures. If, as a *gedankenexperiment*, the blood could be oxygenated outside the body in an artificial lung, the problems would disappear, I suppose.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You still have the problem with there being no gas which is safe in the lungs.  Perhaps you could fill the lungs with fluid and handle gas exchange by other means.